# SQL insert string

Tags: sql

I have a column containing urls:

```
   blah blah http://www.example.com/ID1 blah blah
   blah blah http://www.example.com/ID2 blah blah
   blah blah http://www.example.com/ID3 blah blah
```

I'd like to change:

```
   blah blah [src="http://www.example.com/ID1"] blah blah
   blah blah [src="http://www.example.com/ID2"] blah blah
   blah blah [src="http://www.example.com/ID3"] blah blah
```

Is it possible to do this with a script?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and string replacement functions are usually vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you told us, it sounds like maybe an *update* is what you want:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET url = '[src="' || url || '"]';
```

On some databases which support `CONCAT`, the above would become:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET url = CONCAT('[src="', url, '"]');
```